# Code changes are not published to Local NuGet Package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have a bit of an issue with NuGet Packages.
After changing my code (adding new methods to a class),
I wanted to publish those changes to a local NuGet Package to use it in another project.
I increased the Version 0.2.0 -> 0.2.1 and compiled the project as Release.

And the new Version appears in the other project, but the changes do not.

For some reason a new Nuget Package version is compiled but the changes were not.

Does anyone have experience with this problem?

Help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just ended up recloning my whole project and it worked again.
I will try your advice next time the problem comes up and then inform about the results here.
Thank you:)

Comment: Glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider adding an answer and changing its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :) It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear the cache global-packages folder or it will reference the cache first. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).